# Ubuntu installation freezes - Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-cx0058wm

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP Pavilion Gaming laptop but the installation freezes every time.

Safeboot is disabled and also legacy support is enabled.

Also I have tried other releases and the same thing is happening.

I hope someone can help me out..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while ago when i was installing Ubuntu on my custom built machine. The BIOS setup turned out to be the problem (it was also very old version) and after resetting to default settings i was able to install Ubuntu without encountering any problems. If that fails you could check the bios version and consider updating it.

Comment: Hi, I have updated bios to the newest version and it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to install ubuntu by adding `nomodeset` before `quiet splash` before installation.

Also I have added `nodmodeset` in the GRUB2 settings now so laptop dosen't freeze anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of Graphics Driver.

Use Safe Grapics Mode in the first screen of installtion for the latest 20.04 version.